# How should we calc money (decimal, big.Float)

Tags: go

Can someone tell the right way to calculate finance data in Go. I tryed to use big.Float but prob I miss something. The core goal is to calculate numbers with flaoting point and precision from 2 to 4 without any losses.
`0.15 + 0.15` always should be 0.30.
`float` try:
https://play.golang.org/p/_3CXtRRNcA0
`big.Float` try:
https://play.golang.org/p/zegE__Dit1O

Answer (score 6):

Floating-point is imprecise. Use integers (`int64`) scaled to cents or fractional cents.

---

For example, cents,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    cents := int64(0)
    for i := 0; i <= 2; i++ {
        cents += 15
        fmt.Println(cents)
    }
    fmt.Printf("$%d.%02d\n", cents/100, cents%100)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/k4mJZFRUGVH

Output:

```
15
30
45
$0.45
```

---

For example, hundredths of a cent rounded,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    c := int64(0) // hundredths of a cent
    for i := 0; i <= 2; i++ {
        c += 1550
        fmt.Println(c)
    }
    c += 50 // rounded
    fmt.Printf("$%d.%02d\n", c/10000, c%10000/100)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/YGW9SC7OcU3

Output:

```
1550
3100
4650
$0.47
```

Comment: `int64` cents is pretty good: it gets you to about $92 quadrillion. You might need mills (https://financial-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/mill) for some financial software in which case you're down to just $9 quadrillion :-)

Comment: @torke: Or if you're working with [US fueling stations](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/y6MAAOSw8cNUUpMn/s-l300.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

you can try https://github.com/shopspring/decimal if you really concern about precision,

try this code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/shopspring/decimal"
)

func main() {

    z := decimal.NewFromFloat(0)

    b := decimal.NewFromFloat(0.15)

    z = z.Add(b)
    z = z.Add(b)
    z = z.Add(b)

    fmt.Println("z value:", z)

    testz := z.Cmp(decimal.NewFromFloat(0.45)) == 0

    fmt.Println("is z pass the test? ", testz)

}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/g_fSGlXPKDH

Output:

```
z value: 0.45
is z pass the test?  true
```